# How do I get at the values for multiple data parameters in Meteor iron-router routes?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I've got the following route defined for my small Meteor app:

```
this.route('browse-class', {
    path: '/browse/:_class',
    data: {
        theClass: function() { return this.params._class; },
        numBooks: function() { return Books.find({"class": this.params._class},{sort:{"createdAt": 1}}).count(); },
        books: function() { return Books.find({"class": this.params._class},{sort:{"createdAt": 1}}); }
    }
});
```

What I don't get is how to access the returned values of the data.  Namely, numBooks.  It's supposed to return an integer, but I can't seem to get it to behave with the following code in my Template helper:

```
Template.browseClass.helpers({

    booksFound: function() {
        return this.data.numBooks > 0;
    },

    theOwner: function() {
        theUser = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.owner});
        return theUser.username;
    }

});
```

When I console.log() the value I'm comparing, it seems that it's trying to compare the function instead of the value it returns or something?  I'm sort of confused.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

data should be defined as a function in your route like this :

```
data:function(){
  var booksCursor=Books.find(...);
  return {
    theClass:this.params._class,
    numBooks:booksCursor.count(),
    books:booksCursor
  };
}
```

Then if you specified `browseClass` as the route template, it will be rendered with the result of `data()` as data context, so you can access properties like this :

```
Template.browseClass.helpers({
    booksFound:function(){
      return this.numBooks>0;
    }
});

<template name="browseClass">
  Number of books : {{numBooks}}
  {{#each books}}
    {{...}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: That's awesome.  I knew I was really close to what I needed to do, but that really simplifies things.  Thanks very much.   Testing it now.

Comment: Tested this in my app just now, worked flawlessly, and definitely cleaned up my route.  Thank you so much!